# Why is the derivative of tangent vector always along $y$ axis?

Tags: vector-analysis, curves, tangent-line

Imagine any curve $y=f(x)$ in a cartesian coordinate system. 
At any point, A vector along the tangent can be given as
$$
\vec V = \hat i + \frac{dy} {dx} \hat j
$$
I'm trying to find the direction of $d\vec V$ vector, i.e. : $\vec V(x+dx) - \vec V(x)$

$$
d\vec V = \left(\hat i+\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x+dx} \hat j\right) -  \left(\hat i+\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x} \hat j\right)=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}dx\hat j
$$

> I doubt this result because if I turn my coordinate axes, keeping the curve as such, the vector, mathematically now orients along my new $\hat j'$ axis. As explained in the diagram:  [image]

*Please explain the mistakes in my approach and provide a method to find the direction of $d \vec V$.*

I don't know the math terms used while dealing with vectors like Fields and manifolds. Please understand the situation physically. The components of the vector are obviously real numbers and the vector is 2-dimensional.

Comment: Your gut check is wrong because the acceleration along a circle is only radial if you trace the circle uniformly (that is, with constant speed). The parametrization $(x, f(x))$ that traces out the upper semicircle, for example, has $f(x)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, but this motion is *not* uniform. The tangent vector is $(1, f'(x))$, so the speed is $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$. For the given $f$, we have $f'(x)=-x(R^2-x^2)^{-1/2}$, so the speed is 

$$\sqrt{1+x^2(R^2-x^2)^{-1}}$$

which is obviously not constant for $x\in[-R,R]$. By contrast, the parametrization $(\cos t, \sin t)$ is uniform.

Comment: (To diagnose your error in generic terms, you are confusing the *curve* you trace out with the *motion* you take along it. We can trace out a circle in many different ways; the acceleration vector is a feature of the *motion*, not a feature of the *curve*. It does not make sense to ask "What is the speed at the top of the circle?" without specifying a parametrization. By contrast, the curvature at a point, say, is invariant to the parametrization.)

Comment: yeah...  that is right but This question was once deleted and Now I'm unable to edit. That's why I had to post it as such

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. In any case, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: My doubt: say I use another pair of axes, rotated +45 degrees, keeping the curve unchanged. The equation of curve in new coordinates would be different and the $d\vec V$ vector would be along new Y axis. How can a curve have different $d\vec V$ forna same point?

Comment: Question editted- I've tried to explain the consequences of $d\vec V$ remaining along Y axis, no matter what the function is.

Comment: "the dV vector would be along the new Y axis." No, the acceleration vector won't be vertical in the new coordinates. It's vertical in the old coordinates, not vertical in the new coordinates. That's because, as you note, the equation of the curve changes. The new $x$ coordinate no longer parametrizes itself.

Comment: I think you want to normalize the tangent vector, say make it a unit vector.  Then, $\hat{v} = v_x i + v_y j$ and $\frac{d\hat{v}}{dt}$ will, in general, have both $x$ and $y$ components.

Comment: Obviously, $\frac{d\hat{v}}{dt}$ should not depend on the coordinate system!

Answer (score 1):

To spell out what is mentioned in the comments:

Consider the unit circle parametrized by $x=t$, $y=(1-t^2)^{1/2}$ for $t\in[-1,1]$, where $(x,y)$ are standard Cartesian coordinates. Note that the acceleration vector is vertical everywhere. ("Vertical" here means having standard $x$ coordinate zero.)

Now rotate your axes 45 degrees counterclockwise, and let the new coordinates be $(x', y')$.

Thus $x'=2^{-1/2}(x+y)$, $y'=2^{-1/2}(y-x)$.

So, the point $x=t$, $y=(1-t^2)^{1/2}$ corresponds to the point

$$x'=2^{-1/2}\big(t+(1-t^2)^{-1/2}\big), y'=2^{-1/2}\big((1-t^2)^{-1/2}-t\big)$$

You can clearly see that the acceleration vector of this parametrized curve will *not* have $x'$ coordinate identically equal to zero. In other words, the acceleration vector is *not* "vertical in the new coordinates."

Comment: can't the final equation be written as $y' = f(x')$ by eliminating the parameter? then again the tangent vector would be along $Y'$

Comment: Again you are confusing the curve with the parametrization. Yes, it's true that $y'=f(x')$ (where $f(z)=(1-z^2)^{1/2}$). But the parametrization I give in my answer is NOT the same as the parametrization $x'=t, y'=(1-t^2)^{1/2}$ (for which the acceleration vector *does* point along the $y'$ axis). The point is that when you switch coordinates from $(x,y)$ to $(x', y')$ and fix the initial parametrization $x=t$, $y=(1-t^2)^{1/2}$, you are not free to pick a new parametrization in the new coordinates. The change of coordinates *determines* the new parametrization.

Comment: could you please explain the same thing using the curve $y=x^2$? Its becoming confusing because circle does. not change after the transformation.

Comment: You need to reread my previous comment and do the work yourself. Write down the parametrization $x=t, y=t^2$. The acceleration vector is vertical in these coordinates. Now rotate coordinates by 45 degrees counterclockwise and write down $x'=2^{-1/2}(x+y), y'=2^{-1/2}(y-x)$. You'll see that the second derivative of $x'$ with respect to time is not zero. Thus the acceleration vector is not vertical in the new coordinates, as it ought to be.

Comment: To summarize: whenever you have a motion of the form $x=t, y=f(t)$, the acceleration vector will point along the $y$ axis, simply because the second derivative of $t$ vanishes. But if you change coordinates to $(x', y')$, in general it will no longer be true that $x'=t$, and indeed in general the second derivative of $x'$ will no longer vanish; thus the acceleration vector will not, in general, lie along the $y'$ axis. This is as it should be, because we want to describe the same vector in different coordinates.